# How to add div to text within dynamic nested div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the HTML format code for the nested div

```
<div>
   <div>
         Text 1
        <div>
            Text 2
        </div>
   </div>
</div
```

I want to make this like below using jquery or javascript

```
    <div>
       <div>
             <span class="custom">Text 1</span>
            <div>
                <span class="custom">Text 2</span>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
$('div').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).wrap("<span class=custom></span>")
```

```css
.custom {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    Text 1
    <div>
      Text 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. Use node 3 as anchor since it is text.
2. use `.wrap()` to wrap text in span

Answer (score 1):

```
$([your element selector here]).contents()
                               // get all text nodes
                               .filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 3})
                               // wrap in a span element
                               .wrap('<span />')
                               // add class custom to each element
                               .addClass('custom');
```